# Change the image of a UIButton when a different Button is clicked

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

Before you dive in...
  The ControlState is by Default set to Normal with an Image set

When a user clicks a button it changes the image of the button since i set the target of that button to correspond with the required method. I need to change the image of all other RADIOBUTTONS when the -(void)RADIOBUTTONAClicked: is called

```
-(void)RadioButtonACLicked:{
//code to change radioButton A, the code i have works 
// Code to change all other buttons does not work. 
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
  ....
    // Configure the cell...

```
....
//-------------Creation of Custom Buttons-------------// 
//----RadioButtonA----//
....
[radioButtonA addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonAClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 [radioButtonA setImage:img2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

ButtonB creation

```
radioButtonB = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[radioButtonB addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonBClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[radioButtonB setImage:img2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

so when a radioButton is clicked i need all other buttons Image to set to opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me awhile got it to work

```
(void)radioButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
...

// Sets the UIImage for the custom RadioButtons. 
//img refers to radioOn and img2 refers to radioOff.
// uses an if esle conditional block inorder to correctly change the Images if teh conditions are met.

for(int i=0;i<[self.radioButtons count];i++){
    if ([[self.radioButtons objectAtIndex:i]tag] == sender.tag) {
    [[self.radioButtons objectAtIndex:i] setImage:img2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

[sender setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

```
//When creating the button, set their tags
radioButtonA = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//Add this line
radioButtonA.tag = 111;

radioButtonB = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//Add this line
radioButtonB.tag = 112;
```

Now in

```
-(void)RadioButtonACLicked:{
   //code to change radioButton A, the code i have works 
   //Code to change all other buttons does not work. 
   radioButtonA = [self.view viewWithTag:111];
   radioButtonB = [self.view viewWithTag:112];
   //Change the images for radioButton A and B as you wish
}
```